Error: Deployment failed: The relative import path @astrojs/markdown-remark is missing a prefix (should start with /, ./, or ../)
I upgraded my astro version from "astro": "^4.8.4" to "astro": "^4.16.10", and now I'm facing the following import issue while deploying changes on deno deploy platform.

Error: Deployment failed: The relative import path @astrojs/markdown-remark is missing a prefix (should start with /, ./, or ../)

I have tried to downgrade astro version from 4.16.10 to 4.16.9, 4.16.8, 4.16.7 but I'm still facing the same issue.
